# find -exec command works on Debian Squeeze but not Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, bash, debian

In a shell script (interpreter /bin/bash), the following works on Debian Squeeze:

```
find ~/bin/ '!' -type d -exec dos2unix {} \;
```

Now, I know that for some reason that `dos2unix` was renamed to `fromdos` in Ubuntu, so I'm trying to run:

```
find ~/bin/ '!' -type d -exec fromdos {} \;
```

Whilst this works on Debian, on Ubuntu it yields the output:

```
fromdos: Unable to access file todos.
fromdos: Unable to access file fromdos.
```

How do I get around this, and what is the problem?

Comment: Is the `~/bin/` mentioned exactly the same in both cases? Not just the same file list and contents, but the same underlying device/filesystem?

Comment: ~/bin/ has the same file structure (and files) in both cases. `find ~/bin/ '!' -type d` by itself seems to do the same in both cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On my Ubuntu system, `/usr/bin/{{to,unix2}dos,dos2unix}` are all symlinked to `fromdos`.

Try `type -a fromdos` to see if there's an alias, function or script that's overriding the binary in `/usr/bin`.

Also, try specifying the full path in your `find` command:

```
find ~/bin/ '!' -type d -exec /usr/bin/fromdos {} \;
```

Check to see if there's a broken symlink in your `~/bin` directory. Are there any symlinked directories in `~/bin`?

The error message you're getting looks like `fromdos` is trying to process a file called "fromdos".

Comment: `dos2unix` isn't a symlink on my install. `type -a fromdos` results in `fromdos is /usr/bin/fromdos` and `find ~/bin/ '!' -type d -exec /usr/bin/fromdos {} \;` results in the same error about not being able to find file todos/fromdos. There are no symlinks in `~/bin`.

Comment: @neurolysis: Does `file /usr/bin/fromdos` say "ELF..." or something else? What does `fromdos -V` (capital "V" - version) say? What kind of output do you get from your `find` command if you use the verbose option of `fromdos` (`fromdos -v` - (lower-case "v"))?

Comment: Ah! It was indeed an error, caused by symlinking in a pretty deep subdirectory (no idea how it got there, don't remember doing it). Thanks anyway! :)